# Article scoring algorithm by keywords

Tags: algorithm, text, keyword, scoring

I am looking for an algorithm that can give a score to an article based on weighted keywords.

So suppose I have the following article:

> Economic anxiety amid a dwindling oil and gas industry is raising difficult questions about the future. It is also shaping a Senate race in which a Democrat is seeking re-election in a state long dominated by Republicans.

And I have the following keywords with a given weight (-100 to 100) of importance:

- Economic (50)
- Senate (70)
- Republicans (-100)
- Democrats (100)

This means I want an article that goes about Economy, Senate and Democrats to have a high end score, but an article only about Repulicans to score low. 
One simple solution seems to simply add the values of the keywords occuring in the article. But in reality an article that has 5 times the word Democrats, and 1 times the word Republicans occuring in the text should still have a low ranking.

My question is: are there **efficient** and **effective** algorithms for this problem?

Comment: "But (...) an article that has 5 times the word Democrats, and 1 times the word Republicans (...) should still have a low ranking."
Why? This makes the question not clear to me.

Comment: One could suggest: simply assign a lower weight to "Republicans" (e.g. -350).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you right, you can do it by annotating which words you have already scored in a set. Example in Python:

```py
article = """Economic anxiety amid a dwindling oil and gas industry is raising
             difficult questions about the future. It is also shaping a Senate
             race in which a Democrat is seeking re-election in a state long
             dominated by Republicans."""
keyword_score = {'economic': 50,
                 'senate': 70,
                 'republicans': -100,
                 'democrats': 100}
seen_keywords = set()
score = 0
for word in article.split():
    word = word.lower()
    if word in keyword_score and word not in seen_keywords:
        score += keyword_score[word]
        seen_keywords.add(word)

print(score)
```

That way words will not be scored twice.